# How to say that I have spent a great time in Dubai?

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

If I want to say that I have spent a great time in Dubai then how can I say it in an idiomatic way?
Can I say the following?

> I have spent a great time in Dubai?

Is it idiomatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You  might say "I have spent a great deal of time in Dubai."  or "I have spent a long time in Dubai.", or, as in your post, "a good amount".
If you use "great time", that would mean that you enjoyed your time there, as for example in "I had a great time in Dubai."

Note that you must use "in Dubai".

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I edited my question what I meant to say that I had fun in Dubai, I had spent a great time.

Comment: In that case it's "I had a great time."

Answer (score 1):

No - "a great time" idiomatically means a nice, or enjoyable time.

Some ways you could say that you spent a lot of time there would be:

- I have spent a great deal of time in Dubai
- I have spent a long time in Dubai
- I have spent quite some time in Dubai
- I have spent a considerable amount of time in Dubai.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I edited my question what I meant to say that I had fun in Dubai, I had spent a great time.

Answer (score 0):

> I have spent a great time in Dubai?

It sounds a bit odd.

---

I would rather say:

> I have spent a great deal of time in Dubai.
>
> I have had a great time in Dubai.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I edited my question what I meant to say that I had fun in Dubai, I had spent a great time.